# Override functions.php in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, parent-child

I am new to Wordpress and I am trying to override `functions.php`, with my `functions.php` file in my Child Theme. The original code I wanna change is

```
function generic_read_more_link() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        return ' <a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '" class="more-link">...</a>';
    }
}

add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'generic_read_more_link');

function generic_excerpt_read_more_link($more) {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        global $post;
        return ' <a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink($post->ID)) . '" class="more-link">...</a>';
    }
}

add_filter('excerpt_more', 'generic_excerpt_read_more_link');
add_action('widgets_init', 'generic_widgets_init');
```

To

```
function generic_read_more_link() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        return ' <a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '" class="more-link">Read more</a>';
    }
}

add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'generic_read_more_link');

function generic_excerpt_read_more_link($more) {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        global $post;
        return ' <a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink($post->ID)) . '" class="more-link">Read more</a>';
    }
}

add_filter('excerpt_more', 'generic_excerpt_read_more_link');
add_action('widgets_init', 'generic_widgets_init');
```

However, I have no idea how I need to override it. If I change the words only I will get a blank page only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. **Add your own functions with higher priority**

   ```
   function namespace_read_more_link() {
     if (!is_admin()) {
       return ' <a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '"class="more-link">Read More</a>';
     }
   }

   add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'namespace_read_more_link', 15);
   ```
2. **Remove the parent theme functions**.

   ```
   /* Remove the parent filter */
   function child_remove_parent_read_more() {
     remove_filter('the_content_more_link', 'generic_read_more_link_child');
   }
   add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'child_remove_parent_read_more' );

   /* Add our own filter */
   function namespace_read_more_link() {
     if (!is_admin()) {
       return ' <a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '" class="more-link">Read More</a>';
     }
   }
   add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'namespace_read_more_link');
   ```

For more information, read the article that Dedering posted on [Pluggable Functions in Wordpress](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-overriding-parent-theme-functions-in-your-child-theme--cms-22623).

Answer (score 0):

You can't override it because it's not a pluggable function. [Pluggable Functions](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-overriding-parent-theme-functions-in-your-child-theme--cms-22623)

Answer (score 0):

You cant override those, looks like the `parent-theme` wasn't made so you can.

What you will have to do (and its not ideal) its change the names:

```
function generic_read_more_link_child() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        return ' <a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '" class="more-link">Read more</a>';
    }
}

add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'generic_read_more_link_child');

function generic_excerpt_read_more_link_child($more) {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        global $post;
        return ' <a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink($post->ID)) . '" class="more-link">Read more</a>';
    }
}

add_filter('excerpt_more', 'generic_excerpt_read_more_link_child');
add_action('widgets_init', 'generic_widgets_init');
```

so your `theme-child` functions will also be execute after the `parent` ones, of course this doesn't stop the `parent` ones.